# Writing references so that final file compiles without Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I have been writing my paper in LaTeX and my boss has changed his mind on the journal. The new journal places some restrictions on the use of LaTeX and I probably would have choosen to use Word rather than jump through their hoops. (See link below)

My main problem is that I must supply the document as a single tex file that compiles on a single run of pdflatex. That means no bibtex. I am sure there is a way to get around that will be faster than re writing in Word, but I cannot think how to start.

Please help

https://ecsjournals.msubmit.net/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=display_auth_instructions

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use `\begin{thebibliography}{10}\bibitem{myref} Doe, John. www.example.com\end{thebibliography}` with many bibitems to have all references in your TeX file. But there's still the problem: References won't build up in one pdflatex run.

Comment: you can still use bibtex, just copy in the generated bbl file at the end

Comment: Your link doesn't specify "a single run of pdflatex", which would be very problematic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But that doesn't solve the one-run problem, does it?

Comment: @TeXnician there is no one-run requirement that I see

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In the OP: "a single tex file that compiles on a single run of pdflatex"

Comment: @TeXnician yes but follow the link to see the rules in full (if there was such a requirement it wouldn't really be a problem, you'd just do the same with the aux file)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's a great idea, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use bibtex, just mark things up as normal:

```
\documentclass{report}



\begin{document}


zzz \nocite*

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

then for final submission just paste in the generated  `.bbl` file.

```
\documentclass{report}



\begin{document}


zzz \nocite*

%%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%% \bibliography{xampl}
\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} \newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1}
  \newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} \newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{article-minimal}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 1986.

\bibitem{article-full}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 41(7):73+, July 1986.
\newblock This is a full ARTICLE entry.

\bibitem{article-crossref}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock In {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal\/} \cite{whole-journal}, pages 73+.
\newblock This is a cross-referencing ARTICLE entry.

\bibitem{whole-journal}
{\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 41(7), July 1986.
\newblock The entire issue is devoted to gnats and gnus (this entry is a
  cross-referenced ARTICLE (journal)).

\bibitem{whole-set}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em The Art of Computer Programming}.
\newblock Four volumes. Addison-Wesley,
  {\noopsort{1973a}}{\switchargs{--90}{1968}}.
\newblock Seven volumes planned (this is a cross-referenced set of BOOKs).

\bibitem{inbook-minimal}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Fundamental Algorithms}, chapter 1.2.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, {\noopsort{1973b}}1973.

\bibitem{inbook-full}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Fundamental Algorithms}, volume~1 of {\em The Art of Computer
  Programming}, section 1.2, pages 10--119.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, second edition, 10~January
  {\noopsort{1973b}}1973.
\newblock This is a full INBOOK entry.

\bibitem{inbook-crossref}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Fundamental Algorithms}, section 1.2.
\newblock Volume~1 of {\em The Art of Computer Programming\/} \cite{whole-set},
  second edition, {\noopsort{1973b}}1973.
\newblock This is a cross-referencing INBOOK entry.

\bibitem{book-minimal}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Seminumerical Algorithms}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, {\noopsort{1973c}}1981.

\bibitem{book-full}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Seminumerical Algorithms}, volume~2 of {\em The Art of Computer
  Programming}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, second edition, 10~January
  {\noopsort{1973c}}1981.
\newblock This is a full BOOK entry.

\bibitem{book-crossref}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Seminumerical Algorithms}.
\newblock Volume~2 of {\em The Art of Computer Programming\/} \cite{whole-set},
  second edition, {\noopsort{1973c}}1981.
\newblock This is a cross-referencing BOOK entry.

\bibitem{booklet-minimal}
The programming of computer art.

\bibitem{booklet-full}
Jill~C. Knvth.
\newblock The programming of computer art.
\newblock Vernier Art Center, Stanford, California, February 1988.
\newblock This is a full BOOKLET entry.

\bibitem{incollection-minimal}
Daniel~D. Lincoll.
\newblock Semigroups of recurrences.
\newblock In {\em High Speed Computer and Algorithm Organization}. Academic
  Press, 1977.

\bibitem{incollection-full}
Daniel~D. Lincoll.
\newblock Semigroups of recurrences.
\newblock In David~J. Lipcoll, D.~H. Lawrie, and A.~H. Sameh, editors, {\em
  High Speed Computer and Algorithm Organization}, number~23 in Fast Computers,
  part~3, pages 179--183. Academic Press, New York, third edition, September
  1977.
\newblock This is a full INCOLLECTION entry.

\bibitem{incollection-crossref}
Daniel~D. Lincoll.
\newblock Semigroups of recurrences.
\newblock In Lipcoll et~al. \cite{whole-collection}, pages 179--183.
\newblock This is a cross-referencing INCOLLECTION entry.

\bibitem{whole-collection}
David~J. Lipcoll, D.~H. Lawrie, and A.~H. Sameh, editors.
\newblock {\em High Speed Computer and Algorithm Organization}.
\newblock Number~23 in Fast Computers. Academic Press, New York, third edition,
  September 1977.
\newblock This is a cross-referenced BOOK (collection) entry.

\bibitem{manual-minimal}
{\em The Definitive Computer Manual}.

\bibitem{manual-full}
Larry Manmaker.
\newblock {\em The Definitive Computer Manual}.
\newblock Chips-R-Us, Silicon Valley, silver edition, April-May 1986.
\newblock This is a full MANUAL entry.

\bibitem{mastersthesis-minimal}
{\'{E}}douard Masterly.
\newblock Mastering thesis writing.
\newblock Master's thesis, Stanford University, 1988.

\bibitem{mastersthesis-full}
{\'{E}}douard Masterly.
\newblock Mastering thesis writing.
\newblock Master's project, Stanford University, English Department,
  June-August 1988.
\newblock This is a full MASTERSTHESIS entry.

\bibitem{misc-minimal}
This is a minimal MISC entry.

\bibitem{misc-full}
Joe-Bob Missilany.
\newblock Handing out random pamphlets in airports.
\newblock Handed out at O'Hare, October 1984.
\newblock This is a full MISC entry.

\bibitem{inproceedings-minimal}
Alfred~V. Oaho, Jeffrey~D. Ullman, and Mihalis Yannakakis.
\newblock On notions of information transfer in {VLSI} circuits.
\newblock In {\em Proc. Fifteenth Annual ACM Symposium on the Theory of
  Computing}, 1983.

\bibitem{inproceedings-full}
Alfred~V. Oaho, Jeffrey~D. Ullman, and Mihalis Yannakakis.
\newblock On notions of information transfer in {VLSI} circuits.
\newblock In Wizard~V. Oz and Mihalis Yannakakis, editors, {\em Proc. Fifteenth
  Annual ACM Symposium on the Theory of Computing}, number~17 in All ACM
  Conferences, pages 133--139, Boston, March 1983. The OX Association for
  Computing Machinery, Academic Press.
\newblock This is a full INPROCEDINGS entry.

\bibitem{inproceedings-crossref}
Alfred~V. Oaho, Jeffrey~D. Ullman, and Mihalis Yannakakis.
\newblock On notions of information transfer in {VLSI} circuits.
\newblock In OX{\singleletter{stoc}} \cite{whole-proceedings}, pages 133--139.
\newblock This is a cross-referencing INPROCEEDINGS entry.

\bibitem{whole-proceedings}
The OX Association for Computing Machinery.
\newblock {\em Proc. Fifteenth Annual Symposium on the Theory of Computing},
  Boston, 1983.
\newblock This is a cross-referenced PROCEEDINGS.

\bibitem{proceedings-minimal}
{\em Proc. Fifteenth Annual Symposium on the Theory of Computing}, 1983.

\bibitem{proceedings-full}
Wizard~V. Oz and Mihalis Yannakakis, editors.
\newblock {\em Proc. Fifteenth Annual Symposium on the Theory of Computing},
  number~17 in All ACM Conferences, Boston, March 1983. The OX Association for
  Computing Machinery, Academic Press.
\newblock This is a full PROCEEDINGS entry.

\bibitem{phdthesis-minimal}
F.~Phidias Phony-Baloney.
\newblock {\em Fighting Fire with Fire: Festooning {F}rench Phrases}.
\newblock PhD thesis, Fanstord University, 1988.

\bibitem{phdthesis-full}
F.~Phidias Phony-Baloney.
\newblock {\em Fighting Fire with Fire: Festooning {F}rench Phrases}.
\newblock {PhD} dissertation, Fanstord University, Department of French,
  June-August 1988.
\newblock This is a full PHDTHESIS entry.

\bibitem{techreport-minimal}
Tom Terrific.
\newblock An {$O(n \log n / \! \log\log n)$} sorting algorithm.
\newblock Technical report, Fanstord University, 1988.

\bibitem{techreport-full}
Tom T{\'{e}}rrific.
\newblock An {$O(n \log n / \! \log\log n)$} sorting algorithm.
\newblock Wishful Research Result~7, Fanstord University, Computer Science
  Department, Fanstord, California, October 1988.
\newblock This is a full TECHREPORT entry.

\bibitem{unpublished-minimal}
Ulrich {\"{U}}nderwood, Ned {\~N}et, and Paul {\={P}}ot.
\newblock Lower bounds for wishful research results.
\newblock Talk at Fanstord University (this is a minimal UNPUBLISHED entry).

\bibitem{unpublished-full}
Ulrich {\"{U}}nderwood, Ned {\~N}et, and Paul {\={P}}ot.
\newblock Lower bounds for wishful research results.
\newblock Talk at Fanstord University (this is a full UNPUBLISHED entry),
  November, December 1988.

\bibitem{random-note-crossref}
Volume~2 is listed under Knuth \cite{book-full}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]